# Azure DevOps Test Cases prompting me for Login

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

When I go to a test cases page in Azure DevOps I am getting prompted to enter the username and password.  If I hit cancel and then change the pivot point I can see the test cases.  I didn't have a problem until we upgraded gtom TFS 2017.3 to Azure DevOps 2019.1.1 at this time we went from http to https.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue may related to cache.

Suggest you try to clear all related cache and login with your credentials again. Then check if you still need to login for a test case. This may do the trick.

- [clear VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) and also try to clear **Browser cache**
  such as IE, Chrome.
- Then **clear the Cache Credentials** for the TFS Server on your
  machine.

  You can see them in the Control Panel under: `Control Panel\User
  Accounts\Credential Manager` (or just type "Credentials" into the
  Start Menu).

  Browse down to your tfs server, expand it and then click "Remove".

[image]

Comment: We are seeing the same issue. I tried clearing my credentials, however they were not there. I have tracked it down to a call to an Events endpoint. There is also a number of failed requests to both the Azure Devops Server and Microsoft services before that request.

The microsoft URL: https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track It returns a 400, Invalid Instrumentation key

The Server requests:
404 requests on SelectedColumns, PanePosition, PreviousDetailsPanWidth, PreviousPaneOnPosition, LeftPaneSelectedPanel

401 requests to Events

Comment: I have also found a workaround, put it's on a per project, per user basis. Click column options, then ok. The prompt wont come up after that and the call to SelectedColumns_<projectguid> returns a 200. Seems like a bug in the test case explorer. And I can't post the error, it's too long.